# on pressing enter in contenteditable its copying line style/title to next line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple contententeditable div

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    Line 1 <span title="action">action</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

If the user click at the end of line 1 and press enter, then start typing. The next line also copies the same span's background. How to avoid it?
see demo: https://jsfiddle.net/89z5d2r0/1/

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me why my answer didn't get accepted? so that I could improve my answers next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a non-breaking space or `&nbsp` after the `span` tag to circumvent this behavior. See the snippet below:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f2f3;
}

p span {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    Line 1 <span title="action">action</span>&nbsp
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no text in the p tag and that's why text starts from the span tag. That's why text is written in a span tag with it's properties. At least add `&nbsp` after span tag.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f2f3;
}
p span {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>
    Line 1 <span title="action">action</span>&nbsp
  </p>
</div>
```